# Who do Bash regular expressions seem to fail on simple matches?

Tags: regex, bash

My question is about the Bash binary  operator =~ about which the Bash manual page says the following:

> When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a POSIX extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).   The  return value  is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.

Under the heading *Compound Command* the manual says of an expression in the form:

```
[[ expression ]]
```

> Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression expression.   Expressions  are  composed  of  the  primaries  described below under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS...[and] An additional  binary  operator,  =~, is available...

Which seems to indicate that the =~ operator is available within a compound command of the form

```
[[ <string> =~ <string> ]]
```

Indeed, the following expression invoked at the Bash command-line prompt:

```
[[ 'x' =~ 'x' ]]
```

exits with a return value of `0` which, according to the manual page, indicates the pattern matched.  However:

```
[[ 'x' =~ '.' ]]
```

returns `1` indicating the pattern does not match.  And

```
[[ 'x' =~ '^' ]]
```

also returns `1`.  I have tried this on GNU bash version 5.0.18(1)-release on Debian Linux, and 5.0.17(1)-release on Apple Darwin.

The entry for "regex" in section 7 of the Debian manual (and "re_format" on the Apple machine) begins by indicating that it describes "Regular  expressions ("RE"s), as defined in POSIX.2" of which one form is "modern REs (roughly those of egrep; POSIX.2 calls these 'extended' REs)."  If the *POSIX.2* mentioned in the *regex* page is the same as the *POSIX* mentioned in the *bash* page, then that would mean that the "modern REs" described in the *regex* page are the same as the "POSIX extended regular expressions" that Bash considers the string to the right of the =~ to be.

The *regex* manual entry says further:

- "A (modern) RE is one or more nonempty *branches*"
- "A branch is one or more *pieces*"
- "A piece is an *atom*"
- "An atom is [inter alia] '.' (matching any single character) [or] '^' (matching the null string at the beginning of a line..."

As noted above, this expression:

```
[[ 'x' =~ '.' ]]
```

returns a value `1` indicating no match.  Yet if Bash considers the string to the right of the =~ operator to be a POSIX regular expression, and if the single character '.' can be a POSIX regular expression that matches any single character, and 'x' is a single character, then ought not the string '.' to the right of the =~ operator to match the single character 'x' that is to the left of the =~ operator in the above expression?  If so, then why is the return value `1`?

Similarly, if '^' matches the null string at the beginning of a line, then ought not the string '^" to the right of the =~ operator to match the string 'x' to the left of the =~ operator in the above expression?  If so then why does the expression `[[ 'x' =~ '^' ]]` return `1`?

**Post-solution Update**

chepner's answer (and the comments) provide the working solution.  The following is the relevant excerpt from the bash manual page that I had overlooked:

> Any  part  of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.  Bracket expressions in regular expressions must be treated carefully, since normal quoting characters lose their meanings  between brackets.  If the pattern is stored in a shell variable, quoting the variable expansion forces the entire pattern to be matched as a string.

Comment: Do not quote regex pattern on RHS of `=~`

Comment: If you quote RHS it's a simple string comparison.

Comment: @Cyrus Not quite. It's still, technically, a regular expression match, but quoted metacharacters are treated literals. Here, the entire regular expression is a quoted metacharacter, so the end result is the *same* as a string comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted characters in a regular expression are treated literally, not as a regex metacharacters. `[[ 'x' =~ '.' ]]` is equivalent to `[[ 'x' = . ]]`.

Dropping the quotes works as expected:

```
$ [[ 'x' =~ . ]] && echo works
works
```

For this reason, you often use an unquoted parameter expansion to specify a regular expression.

```
$ regex=.  # or regex='.'
$ [[ 'x' =~ $regex ]] && echo works
works
```

Comment: Another reason to use a separate variable to hold the pattern is that the quoting rules have changed at some point and this way works across that change, see [Pitfall #35](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5B.5B_.24foo_.3D.2BAH4_.27some_RE.27_.5D.5D).